# ROS beginner tutorials building nodes issue

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working through the ROS begnner tutorials, specifically on this section I am running into an issue:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

I am using ROS kinetic and Ubuntu16.04 LTS.

I section 3, I have added the extra lines below to the CMakeLists.txt file:

> add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)

> target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

> add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

> add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)

> target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

> add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

Once these are added, I have saved the .txt file and have then run the following command to add dependencies for the executable targets to message generation targets:

> add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

**Note that the abve command had to be edidet to escape the brackets, it now looks like below:**

> add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

However, when I run this command I get the following error:

> add_dependencies(talker: command not found

I am unsure why this is, I have seen similar issues on forums such as here https://answers.ros.org/question/67415/beginner-tutorial-catkin_make-error-directory-not-found/?answer=257676?answer=257676#post-id-257676, but could not find a solution for mine, maybe I have missed the solution somewhere.

Has anyone come across this before and has a solution?

**Below is my CMakeLists.txt file** (Note that I have put a . between the # so as the text does not look so large.

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

> project(beginner_tutorials)

> .#.# Find catkin and any catkin packages

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS

> roscpp

> rospy

> std_msgs

> message_generation

> )

> .#.#. Declare ROS messages and services

> add_message_files(

> FILES

> Num.msg

> )

> add_service_files(

> FILES

> AddTwoInts.srv

> )

> .#.# Generate added messages and services

> generate_messages(

> DEPENDENCIES

> std_msgs

> )

> .#.# Declare a catkin package

> catkin_package(

> CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime

> )

> .#.# Build talker and listener

> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}

> )

> add_executable(

> talker src/talker.cpp

> )

> target_link_libraries(

> talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

> )

> add_dependencies(

> talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp

> )

> add_executable(

> listener src/listener.cpp

> )

> target_link_libraries(

> listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

> )

> add_dependencies(

> listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp

> )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351786/ros-beginner-tutorials-building-nodes-issue/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-08**:\

> Note that I have put a . between the # so as the text does not look so large.

that is because you are using `>`, which are for quoting ordinary text, not code (or build scripts, or terminal copy-pastes, etc).

If you want to format blocks *verbatim* (as would be needed for code, console text, etc), then paste the text into your question, select all the lines and press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it), or press `ctrl+k`. That should format everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have [..] then run the following command to add dependencies for the executable targets to message generation targets:

> ```
> add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
> ```

Similar to your other question (#q351468): what you show is not a command you run in the terminal, but another statement to add to the `CMakeLists.txt` of the package.

From the `CMakeLists.txt` you show it would appear it's already there, so things should be OK like this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1